# Making sure a user is authenticated in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, authentication, cookies

I'm making an angular app that uses a directive called ng-auth to hide/display elements based on a user's login status.  For example:

```
<div ng-auth="! isAuthenticated()">
    <a href="/login">Log-in</a> //Shows if user is not logged in
</div>

<div ng-auth="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Welcome {{ user }}</p> //Shows if user is logged in
</div>
```

I have to assume that the user has complete control of the client and will have access to all "protected" elements that I would normally display. I know this involves a separation of concerns involving validating all sensitive requests with the server. Now, I have a couple questions:

1. How would I be able to display sensitive information in the view? If instead of `Welcome {{ user }}` I wanted to show `{{ user.sensitiveInformation }}`, how would I handle this?
2. How do I *actually* validate the user with the server? From my understanding I am supposed to send the cookie containing the session id to the server for validation. But, what stops a user from sending somebody else's cookie? Or spoofing a response from the server to trick the client into showing some information.

Comment: Have a look at this http://digitalturnip.com/maintaining-session-info-in-angularjs-when-you-refresh-the-page/

Comment: I believe this solution is insecure. The login status is unsafely stored as a client-side cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases, you can use restful authentication system. For every request, you send access_token to server in order to know user has logged in or not. For example;

1. Your customer entered username and password on your login form and
   pressed Enter.
2. Username and password sent to server and validated in db.
3. After success validation, you generate an access token by using
   username and password and return to client.
4. On client side, you stroe it on local storage.

After now, you will send that access token for every request in order to validate this request belongs logged in user.

For detailed example please refer [here](https://github.com/cubuzoa/NDEx-Site)

For googling: [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=restful%20authentication%20system&oq=restful%20authentication%20system)